# AWS .NET SDK illegal keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, amazon-s3

I'm using Amazon's [AWS .NET SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sdkfornet/) to connect to Amazon's S3.

PutObjectRequest's WithKey() method automatically encodes any string you throw at it, however there are still some patterns it cannot handle.  Not handling the keys means throwing the following error:

```
Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: The request signature we calculated 
does not match the signature you provided
```

I have found little to no documentation on legal keys from Amazon.  What patterns are illegal to use in S3 keys and throw this exception?

Answer (score 3):

I have created a method to normalize slash in keys while uploading to

```
private static string NormalizeKey(string relativePath)
    {
           return relativePath.Replace("~/", "").Replace(@"~\", "").Replace(@"\", @"/").Replace(@"//", @"/");
    }
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks Shoaib! I have a similar method to avoid accidentally creating folders when building my keys.  What is the tilde '~' for in the Replace calls?  Without it seems to work fine for me.

Comment: ~ is used in my code because i have setup my relative path like they exist in my local project. in your case this could be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

In my particular case, the problem was two-fold:

1. Amazon cannot handle the backslash '\' character in the keys
2. Amazon does not allow folders to end in a period

I have written the following two methods to help when building my keys:

```
// Cleans a piece of a key - a folder name or final object name:
//  - replaces illegal characters with valid ones
//  - avoids accidental folder creation by removing slashes inside the key
private string CleanPartialKey(string partialKey)
{
    return partialKey.Replace('/', '-') // Add slashes separately - avoid creating accidental folders
                     .Replace('\\', '_'); // Amazon knows not how to deal with backslashes, so replace them with something else
}

// Ensures a full key does not have any illegal patterns.
// This should only be called with a complete key
private string CleanKey(string fullKey)
{
    return fullKey.Replace("./", "/"); // ending a folder with a period is illegal
}
```